# Looping sprite scrolling background

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, side-scroller, phaser-framework

I'm new in WebGL and I decided to try the Phaser.js library.

I'm having some trouble with background scrolling (games like runner and side scrollers).
I've seen how it works in PIXI.js, but I cant do / find a solution for Phaser.

Pixi.js code.

```
function init() {
    var farTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("resources/bg-far.png");
    far = new PIXI.TilingSprite(farTexture, 512, 256);
    far.position.x = 0;
    far.position.y = 0;
    far.tilePosition.x = 0;
    far.tilePosition.y = 0;
    stage.addChild(far);
    requestAnimFrame(update);
}
function update() {
    far.tilePosition.x -= 0.128;
    renderer.render(stage);
    requestAnimFrame(update);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in Phaser would be:

```
var far;

function preload() {

    game.load.image('imageKey', 'resources/bg-far.png');

}

function create() {

    far = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 512, 256, 'imageKey');

}

function update() {

    far.tilePosition.x -= 0.128;

}
```